# echarts: How to use only one of dataZoom's zoom and back

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to use only one dataZoom.

how to use that?

When operated with show's boolean, both icons appear or both disappear.

I want to use only one of dataZoom's zoom and back....

Sorry if my question is weird or unclear.

```
toolbox:{

    feature: {
        dataZoom: {
              title: {
              zoom: "" //i don't wanna use that(zoom) 
              back: "Zoom Out" //i wanna use back.
              },
      },
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the 'icon' property as an invalid path, and the zoom icon won't show.

```
dataZoom: {
    show: true,
    title: {
        zoom: 'Redefinir zoom',
        back: ''
    },
    icon: {
        back: 'blank'
    },
    iconStyle: {
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 2,
    }
}
```

In my example, I didn't want the 'back' icon, so I set it's title as a blank string (just as you did) and set its icon path as 'blank' (which is an invalid path), and now the icon doesn't show.